# Why is not "Ellie" == "Ellie", when one of them was read from the user?

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

The following question is from a quiz I took a few weeks ago and got incorrect, but the answer wasn't provided:

> Consider the following code, which contains no compile errors:
>
> ```
> String secret = "Ellie";
> Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
> System.out.println("Guess which name I'm thinking of:");
> String guess = kb.next();
>
> if (guess == secret)
> {
>     System.out.println("Wow! You're smart!");
> }
> else
> {
>     System.out.println("Wrong!");
>     System.out.println("You guessed: " + guess);
>     System.out.println("The correct answer was: " + secret);
> }
> ```
>
> Suppose the user enters "Ellie" at the prompt.
>   What output would result, and why that output and not the other output?

Here was my incorrect answer:

> The output would be the else statement "WRONG!" because of the capitalization of the letter 'E'. A solution to this would be
>   to either change the String secret to "ellie" as well as the user's guess, or one can write in the ignoreCase keyword to
>   String secret.

The program actually outputs "Wrong", I tested it.

Aside from simply knowing the answer, could someone really explain this to me so I can understand the concept better?

Comment: You were right with your answer except for the wrong reason, it actually has to do with the `guess == secret` part.

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase` would be used to compare "Ellie" and "eLLie" and still get `true`. `equals` would be enough to compare "Ellie" and "Ellie".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The == does a reference comparison, and so it'll always say 'Wrong!', even if the two string references are equal.  In order for it to match correctly, it would have to use `secret.equals( guess )`.

Comment: That's actually not quite right. You will not always get "Wrong!". The JVM might decide to reuse the "Ellie" string instance, in which case you would get a correct. The behavior is simply undefined.

Comment: Point taken.  Any idea the chances this happens?

Comment: I assume it is actually quite likely, but i'm not sure. If you really want to know, writing a little program to test that shouldn't be to difficult ;).

Comment: @Chronial: Actually, this is quite defined in the [language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#19369). All equal string literals and other string compile time constants are also identical objects. Also, everything which got `intern()`ed is identical to these. Strings created by `new` are new objects, not identical to anything existing before. Strings read in from the user quite likely fresh strings (but this depends on the implementation of the scanner's `next` method here - it could call `intern`, though this would not be a good idea).

Comment: @Shawn: feel free to include parts of my explanation into your answer.

Answer (score 3):

In java:

- the `==` operator tests if the two objects are the same exact instance
- the .equals() method of String compares if the objects "have the same value"

Since the user input the value, it's a *new* instance of String, so it will never be true that `secret == input`.

You should always use `str1.equals(str2)` when comparing Strings.